# Exchange to use second damain as users default email address

Tags: exchange

I am using Exchange 2019 and have setup a second domain, but when a user received an email on this second domain and will answer to this email, the answer always will be send from his default email address, which is a one from the primary domain.
These is a problem, becauce the send address must be changed by hand all the time.

How can I change the default to the secondary domain?
Or what else can I do to solve this problem?

The user wold not require a email address from the primary domain!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you reply via OWA, will your address still be overwritten by your primary email address?
You can refer to the following command to enable sending from email alias for Exchange Online mailboxes：

```
Set-OrganizationConfig - SendFromAliasEnabled $true
```

Note: This feature is in preview and not yet generally available. Admins should test and fully understand the client impact and known issues before enabling this feature in your tenant.

For more details on this feature, please refer to this link:
[Sending From Email Aliases – Public Preview - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/sending-from-email-aliases-public-preview/ba-p/3070501)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the email address policy to assign each user an address in the second SMTP domain, and to use it as the reply address.

If you don't need it, you can also remove from the policy the automatic generation of an email address in the first SMTP domain.

Comment: Massimo,
is there any way to use the second domain as the primary domain for a specific user?
This user don't need a adress in the primary domain!

Comment: Yes, you can configure this both in email address policies (globally or for a group of users) or for each user in the mailbox properties.

Comment: If I try to add a additional address format to the policy, I have to choose a specific pattern, wich I don't want to use.
Currently I am using the Default Policy. If I try to set up a new one, I always have to a predefined pattern for the second domain.
I also have not find a way how to remove the automatic generation of the email address in the first domain.

Comment: You can remove the address in the first domain only after you add an address in the second domain and set it as primary (reply).

Comment: If you can't (or don't wan't to) use a generic format, then you can't use address policies and you need to configure this individually for each mailbox; the same caveat applies: you can only remove the primary address after you add another one and set it as primary.